# List.Except not using custom Equals function

Tags: c#

```
public class eq : IEquatable<eq>
    {
        public string s1;
        public string s2;
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;
            eq o = obj as eq;
            if (o == null) return false;
            return Equals(o);
        }
        public bool Equals(eq o)
        {
            if (s1==o.s1 && s2==o.s2)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        public eq (string a,string b)
        {
            s1 = a;
            s2 = b;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<eq> l1 = new List<eq>();
            List<eq> l2 = new List<eq>();
            l1.Add(new eq("1", "1"));
            l1.Add(new eq("2", "2"));
            l1.Add(new eq("3", "3"));
            l2.Add(new eq("3", "3"));
            l2.Add(new eq("1", "1"));
            var b= l1.Contains(new eq("1", "1"));
            var v = l1.Except(l2);
        }
    }
```

The `l1.contains` statement calls the custom function and returns the expected result

`l1.Except` does not result in a call to the custom function and returns the entire contents of `l1`

Is there a way to accomplish this without writing loops explicitly?

Comment: In first place if you want you can use _lambda expression_ or _delegates_ to make the comparer instead of define the inheritance of the _IEquatable<T>_

Comment: Either use a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` for `Except` or override `Equals` + `GetHashCode`.

Comment: You do realize that you don't actually have a custom Equals method, right? `public bool Equals (eq o)` is not the correct signature for the Equals method. The correct signature is `public override bool Equals(object obj)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should override `GetHashCode` method for `Except` to work properly. E.g

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 19;
    hash = hash * 23 + (s1 == null) ? 0 : s1.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 23 + (s2 == null) ? 0 : s2.GetHashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

Except performs set operation (internally it fills `Set<T>` with items from second sequence and tries to add items from first sequence to same set).

Comment: From a string handling perspective, can I assume that if 2 strings are  equal, their hashes will be equal? (they should be as per my understanding, but strings can be weird sometimes)

Comment: @Akash if strings are equal then hashes should be equal. But you have two string fields here

Comment: Yup..  just wanted to recheck if s1==s2 then hash(s1)==hash(s2).  Understood the point behind implementing GetHash

Comment: @Akash A requirement of all hash codes is that if two objects will compare equal, they *must* return the same hash code.

Comment: @Akash yep, when item is added/retrieved from set - item's hashcode is used

Comment: If either s1 or s2 is null, it'll crash; e.g. for eq test = new eq(null, null);

Answer (score 3):

var v = l1.Where(x => !l2.Contains(x));

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `Except` (and `Set<T>`, `Dictionary<K, T>`) uses *hash codes* first, and only then (*on hash codes conflict*, when two hash codes are the same) - `Equals`, that's why *whenever you redesign* `Equals` you *should implement* `GetHashCode` as well. In your case:

```
public class eq : IEquatable<eq> {
    public string s1;
    public string s2;

    // Your code could be shortened
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
      return Equals(obj as eq);
    }

    public bool Equals(eq o) {
      // Do not forget, that "o" can be null
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, o)) 
        return false;

      return String.Equals(s1, o.s1) && String.Equals(s2, o.s2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
      // There's a possibility that either s1 or s2 are nulls  
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s1))
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s2))
          return 0;
        else
          return s2.GetHashCode();
      else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s2))
        return s1.GetHashCode();

      // Typical trick: xoring hash codes 
      return s1.GetHashCode() ^ s2.GetHashCode();      
    }
```